# Как правильно скрыть java script на фронте в записи Wordpress, если обфускатором не получилось?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, безопасность, запись

Вставил с помощью блока "Код" в новом текстовом редакторе записей Wordpress javascript программку, только теперь не знаю, как ее скрыть на фронте. Попробовал прогнать через онлайн обфускатор:

https://www.daftlogic.com/projects-online-javascript-obfuscator.htm

Получилось такое:

```
e`val(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d`
```

Но при вставке в запись wordpress в таком виде программу не воспринимает, пишет, что код содержит элементы с ошибкой. Может, подскажете, кто сталкивался, как выйти из этого положения?

Comment: Зачем это скрывать? У тебя супер пупер код достойный нобелевской премии?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а вдруг кто-нибудь зайдёт на супер-пупер сайт, увидит супер-пупер код, скопирует себе без разрешения и станет бесплатно использовать?! Это же воровство вселенского масштаба!

Comment: Да ладно вам ребят, серьёзно ведь нужно помочь. Я бы на вашем месте лицензировал код под какой-нибудь [лицензией от CC](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/#licenses) (Я в них не особо разбираюсь, но поищите ту которая запрещает распространение продукта, если такая есть вообще), если кто-то решит скопировать код, то тогда можно будет ему угрожать судом. Ну или можете сами написать лицензию, но тут уже будет тяжеловато самому делать.

Comment: @ΝNL993 скопировать код...... все даже в дипломных работах давно знают, как сделать так, чтобы процент оригинальности повысить до 85%  :)) С кодом тоже самое))  К тому же, мне ничто не мешает код использовать в своей закрытой системе ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну всё равно лучше, чем вообще никакой вариант.

Comment: Отправляйте все действия и связяанные с ним элементы на сервер и там делайте всё что вам нужно :) Всё что смогут у вас скопировать - это слушатели действий и запросы, код сервера просто так точно не скопируют :) (шутка так делать не надо)